# Callan–Symanzik equation, Renormalization, Bare quantities and Green functions relations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, greens-functions

I am studying the renormalization procedure from the Ramond book. I understand the computation but I miss some physical insight. I will present my understanding here and the question that I have in mind.

So we start from a Lagrangian density (scalar $\lambda \phi^4$ theory)

$$ L_i(\phi, m, \lambda^*)$$

which Green functions are divergent.

So we regularize it using dimensional regularization introducing the scale $\mu$. We then have the divergences explicitly showing as $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ or similar terms (dim=4 means $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$). So the lagrangian is now

$$ L_i(\phi, m, \lambda^*, \epsilon )$$

We define $\lambda = \mu^{-2 \epsilon} \lambda^* $ to be dimensionless in $4-\epsilon$ dimensions while $\lambda^*$ is not.

So we add some counterterms which are chosen to produce diagrams with the same divergences as the one we calculated (e.g. the tadpole) with the opposite sign, so to make finite the green functions (we can choose different schemes etc), having

$$L_{ren}(\phi, m, \mu, \lambda, \epsilon )= L_i(\phi, m, \lambda^*, \epsilon)- L_{ct}(\phi, m, \mu, \lambda, \epsilon )$$

1. $L_{ct}$ has the same functional structure as the original lagrangian $L_i$, is that correct?

So we can go on and say that also $L_{ren}$ has the same functional structure and write it in the same form as $L_i$ but with new fields and coupling constants as

$$L_{ren} (\phi_0, m_0, \lambda_0, \mu, \epsilon)$$

so $L_{ren}$ has the same form as $L_i$.

2. What is the meaning of $\phi_0$, $m_0$ and $\lambda_0$? Which are now the physical quantities?

   2.0 EDIT: what is the meaning of the bare quantities? They are divergent but they appear in the renormalized Lagrangian.

   2.1 EDIT: what is the meaning of $m$ and $\lambda$ in the original Lagrangian, are they physical quantities?

Then we can study the path integral. We have the renormalized partition function $Z_{ren}$ that is, we added the counterterms to the original Lagrangian, and in the exponent, we have $L_{ren}$, the integration is over the original field $\phi$ and the original source $J$.

We can define another path integral building it with $L_{ren}$, but integrating in $\phi_0$ and using another source $J_0$.
And there is a relation between the Green functions obtained from the two different path integrals:

$$ G(x_k, m,\lambda, \mu) = Z_{\phi}^{N/2}G(x_k, m_0, \lambda_0)$$

where $Z_{\phi}$ is the wave function renormalization.

3. How can I interpret this relation? What is the physical meaning? The physical green function should be the one on the left, built from the renormalization procedure.

Comment: 1) Yes, it has the same structure - for your example, counterterms will be like $-\frac{1}{2}(Z_m - 1) \phi^2$ - the mass counterterm, the counterterm for kinetic term : $ -\frac{1}{2}(Z_\phi - 1) \partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi $ and the vertex counter term $(Z _\lambda - 1) \lambda \phi^4 / 4!$. 2) The bare quantities are not physical - the real physical quantities are the renormalized couplings, mass is extracted from the pole of full propagator, and interaction coupling from the amplitudes and cross-sections

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. In question 2) so are the physical quantities $m$, $\lambda$ of the original Lagrangian $Li(ϕ,m,λ^∗)$? Or not even them. 
At this point I have $m_0$, $\lambda_0$, $\mu$, $\lambda$ and $m$ connected between them. The bare quantities contains infinities right? Because the incorporate also the counterterms.

Comment: Which pages in Ramond?

Comment: @FrancescoCosta the physical $\lambda, m$ are obtained when accounting for the diagrams and divergences in perturbation theory, the bare quantitities in the Lagrangian are usually infinite and after calculating the diverging diagrams, their contribution cancel the original infinities in the Lagrangian

Comment: @Qmechanic it's pages172-173, Chapter 4 Section 5

Comment: @spiridon_the_sun_rotator the things that confuse me are 2. That we have in the renormalized lagrangian the bare (divergent) quantities. And second, I don't understand the meaning of the original $m$ and $\lambda$ (that are not the bare quantities as defined above)